# Table Cell into two lines in iOS

Tags: uitableview

I'm working on iOS App and I want the text label to be in two lines. I found the following code but it doesn't seem to work. Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong?

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

        [[cell textLabel] setNumberOfLines:2];

        cell.textLabel.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
        cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:10.0];

        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
    }
    //Configure cell
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
 [[cell textLabel] setNumberOfLines:0];
```

Comment: It works fine for me.Please check my sample code here https://github.com/slysid/iOS/tree/master/MutlipleLineCell

Answer (score 0):

I have tested it and this is working fine..

```
cell.textLabel.numberOfLines=2
```

Comment: Thanks @Ashish…I used @slysid's proposal and got the problem resolved. Thanks for the suggestion though.